dplyr mutate case_when grepl not returning values correctly in R
In the given dataset i have cash , other as well as cash.other at position 7.
df <- data.frame(values = c("loan", "cash", "equity", 
"other", "commercial.news", "money.news", "cash.other"))

I am trying to return grepl("cash.other", tolower(values)) ~ "Cash_Other" but it is returning it as Cash.
In the original dataframe i have cash, other and cash.other as well, which is why i need a to return cash.other as Cash_Other
df <- df %>%
  mutate(values = case_when(
    grepl("loan", tolower(values))  ~ "Lond",
    grepl("cash", tolower(values))  ~ "Cash",
    grepl("equity", tolower(values)) ~ "Equity",
    grepl("other", tolower(values)) ~ "Other",
    grepl("commercial.news", tolower(values)) ~ "Commercial_News",
    grepl("money.news", tolower(values)) ~ "Money_News",
    grepl("cash.other", tolower(values)) ~ "Cash_Other",
    TRUE ~ as.character(values)
  ))

df

How do i return Cash_Other when the case is cash.other?
           values
1            Lond
2            Cash
3          Equity
4           Other
5 Commercial_News
6      Money_News
7            Cash


your issue is that grepl("cash", tolower(values))  ~ "Cash", and also grepl("other", tolower(values)) ~ "Other", both cover cash.other

Not sure if Lond as replacement for loan is a typo, but if you wish to convert to CamelCase, then try the following:
library(snakecase)
df <- data.frame(values = c("loan", "cash", "equity", 
                            "other", "commercial.news", "money.news", "cash.other"))
df$values2 <- snakecase::to_upper_camel_case(df$values, sep_out = "_")
#            values         values2
# 1            loan            Loan
# 2            cash            Cash
# 3          equity          Equity
# 4           other           Other
# 5 commercial.news Commercial_News
# 6      money.news      Money_News
# 7      cash.other      Cash_Other


Just changing the order of the grepls seems to work.
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(values = c("loan", 
                            "cash", 
                            "equity", 
                            "other", 
                            "commercial.news", 
                            "money.news", 
                            "cash.other"))


df %>%
  mutate(values = case_when(
    grepl("loan", tolower(values))  ~ "Lond",
    grepl("cash.other", tolower(values)) ~ "Cash_Other",
    grepl("cash", tolower(values))  ~ "Cash", # Cash after Cash_Other
    grepl("equity", tolower(values)) ~ "Equity",
    grepl("other", tolower(values)) ~ "Other", # Other after Cash_Other
    grepl("commercial.news", tolower(values)) ~ "Commercial_News",
    grepl("money.news", tolower(values)) ~ "Money_News",
    TRUE ~ as.character(values)
  ))


           values
1            Lond
2            Cash
3          Equity
4           Other
5 Commercial_News
6      Money_News
7      Cash_Other

Be careful with the conditions.

Here's another option:
> sapply(strsplit(df$values, "\\."), \(x) {
    paste0(tools::toTitleCase(tolower(x)), collapse = "_")})
[1] "Loan"  "Cash"  "Equity"  "Other"  "Commercial_News"  "Money_News" 

"Cash_Other"
